# How to get customer counter?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.2.2 version, In the front end footer, I need a counter to view on. of users/transactions count. Is it possible? If yes, please provide me the code.

Comment: What do you mean by users/transactions count ? you want to display a counter of the registered users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of orders using:

```
$nrOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getSize();
```

You can get the number of customers using:

```
$nrCustomers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getSize();
```

Comment: I need the number of registered users on my site footer

Comment: Please see my updated answer